# Testing React/Redux components and containers using <Provider />

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am writing react container components at the moment that use the `connect()` wrapper/decorator. I'm interested in providing a fake store to my container when I test using `mocha` and `expect` / `should`. After reading the documentation I should `export` a flat/simple version of my component and then in the test use `<Provider ...>`. Below is a link to the documentation.

https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/WritingTests.md

However I am struggling to find an example/guideline on actually implementing this. I understand the documentation might omit it as its obvious but I am lost trying to hook up my tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [redux-mock-store](http://arnaudbenard.com/redux-mock-store/) before and using `Provider` around the connected component to test rendering (I used [enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme)) and interactions.

To test mapStateToProps:

1. create mock store with initial state
2. render component
3. assert expectations against the component

To test mapDispatchToProps:

1. create mock store with initial state
2. render component
3. trigger action in component
4. assert expectation against the mock store